# how to change joomla basic url update in joomla 3.6.4?

Tags: joomla

how to change joomla basic url update in joomla 3.6.4 ?

for example:
https://**update.joomla.org**/core/extensions/com_joomlaupdate.xml

change to:
http://**update.myWeb.net**/core/extensions/com_joomlaupdate.xml

**[image for this question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDJYH.png)**

Answer (score 0):

You can change that thru your database:

In the table (dbprefix)_update_sites, the location url.